# Why does NSString not respond to selector longValue but does respond to longLongValue and intValue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I am trying to get the `long` value of an `NSString` by calling `longValue`, but `NSString` doesn't respond to `longValue`. It, however, *does* respond to `intValue` and `longLongValue`.

Is this the intended behavior? If yes, why? I can't see a logical reason for it to respond to `intValue` and `longLongValue`, but not `longValue`.

I can add a category on `NSString` and add:

```
-(long)longValue{
    return (long)[self longLongValue];
}
```

This solves my problem. But I still don't understand why this not the default implementation.

Comment: I can't think of a logical reason why they didn't provide that and I'm guessing only certain former-NeXTSTEP engineers know the reason.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit 1:**

This should answer you as to why we can't get a longValue from NSString [Major 64-bit changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html)

**First Answer:**

Apple's documentation speaks of getting only the following Numeric types:

```
doubleValue
floatValue
intValue
integerValue
longLongValue
boolValue
```

[Apple's doc on NSString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/longLongValue)

So Probably one of the Ways to get a **longValue from a NSString** Type is how you are doing it.

I am not sure that you will get the intended result as you are type casting to longValue.

However, the other possible way to get a longValue from NSString would be:

`NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
long number = [[numberFormatter numberFromString:string] longValue];`

Comment: I've checked the documentation after getting the error. I already know that it doesnt't exist. My question is: why?

Comment: This should answer as to why.. [Major 64-bit changes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want 64-bit across all CPU architectures then you want `long long` or `int64_t`, which is catered for with:

```
[NSString longLongValue]
```

Comment: I don't recall saying I wanted 32-bit integers anywhere. I need 64-bit across all platforms.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu OK updated my answer, however it's not clear what you do want.  In your question you state you want `long`, which is 32- or 64-bit, depending on CPU architectures, and now you are saying you want 64-bit everywhere.

Comment: I don't think it's about what I want, but why the Cocoa[ Touch] API is inconsistent. I mean, if there is `floatValue`, `doubleValue`, `intValue`, `longLongValue`, I intuitively and normally expect to see `longValue` too. I understand that it *may* be related to bitness-consistency across platforms, but it creates confusion, IMHO.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Doesn't sound like a question related to programming as the answer will largely be opinion-based.